# Looking for a comic with a Race to the End of Time?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, episode-identification, the-flash

I've been trying to remember which comic I saw this in. It was Superman and The Flash running through time till they got to this net-like thing at the end of time.  I remember reading this in the 80s, but it was a beat-up comic, so it could have been earlier. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### DC Comics Presents Vol 1 [#1](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/DC_Comics_Presents_Vol_1_1) and [#2](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/DC_Comics_Presents_Vol_1_2) (1978)

The title of these comics are Superman and The Flash, with the first one having a bubble saying

> The Man of Steel and the Scarlet Speedster embark on a deadly to CHASE to the END of TIME

and

> The Man of Steel and the Scarlet Speedster run a deadly RACE to the END of TIME

It seems that there are two warring peoples from a similar species, a scientist from one of the peoples is attempting to merge the species but this would have a drastic effect on the humans.

[image: DC Comics Presents Vol 1 #1]
[image]

Comment: That's it! I remember that alien now, too. Thanks!